# FK References 2 Subclass Error when adding data

Tags: sql, database, oracle, foreign-keys, subclass

I am having problems when I add values to this table. The bottom two FK constraints are referencing subclass entities which share the same PK. I have values added in the appropriate subclasses.

Oracle is kicking this Error: ORA-02291

I'm pretty sure what is causing it is that the table cannot tell which table to reference the FK to. Is there a check I can run to have it pass through both of the tables to check which table the FK belongs to?

```
CREATE TABLE Lease(  
leaseNo       CHAR(9),    
duration      NUMBER(1) NOT NULL,    
inDate        DATE      NOT NULL,    
outDate       DATE,    
matNo           CHAR(9),    
plNo            CHAR(9),

CONSTRAINT  lease_pk      PRIMARY KEY (leaseNo),    
CONSTRAINT  student_fk  FOREIGN KEY (matNo) REFERENCES Student(matNo),    
CONSTRAINT  bedroom_fk  FOREIGN KEY (plNo)  REFERENCES BedRoom(plNo),
CONSTRAINT  hallroom_fk FOREIGN KEY (plNo)  REFERENCES HallRoom(plNo)
);
```

Full Model:

[image]

Comment: Please show *all* relevant info. This is a *runtime* error. Show your input table data and output table data, code you ran and the error message. You must do this for a "what's wrong with my code" question.

Comment: And don't use CHAR datatype, you'll have problems. Use varchar2.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the ability to change the schema? If so, you may want to consider collapsing tables `BedRoom` and `HallRoom` into a single `Room` table. Then introduce a `RoomType` table to hold the types ('Hall' and 'Bed'). Then `Room` has a FK to `RoomType` and `Lease` has a FK to `Room`. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE RoomType(
    id NUMBER
   ,type VARCHAR2(32)
);


CREATE TABLE Room(
    plno      VARCHAR2(9)
   ,room_type VARCHAR2(32)
   ,rmno      VARCHAR2(4)
   ,rent      NUMBER(6,2)
   ,roomno    VARCHAR2(9)

   ,CONSTRAINT room_pk PRIMARY KEY (plno)
   ,CONSTRAINT room_room_type_fk FOREIGN KEY(room_type) REFERENCES RoomType(id)    
);


CREATE TABLE Lease(  
    leaseNo    VARCHAR2(9),
   ,duration   NUMBER(1) NOT NULL
   ,inDate     DATE      NOT NULL    
   ,outDate    DATE
   ,matNo      CHAR(9)
   ,plNo       CHAR(9)

   ,CONSTRAINT  lease_pk PRIMARY KEY (leaseNo)
   ,CONSTRAINT  student_fk FOREIGN KEY(matNo) REFERENCES Student(matNo)
   ,CONSTRAINT  room_fk FOREIGN KEY(plNo) REFERENCES Room(plNo)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have *told* the DBMS that there are FK constraints from plno to tables Bedroom and Hallroom. So there is no "cannot tell which table to reference the FK to". A FK constraint says that listed columns' values in the referencing table must appear in corresponding columns in the referenced table. We call a column list a FK when it is the referencing list in one *or more* FK constraints.

This is a *runtime* error. You have failed to put a value into one of Bedroom or Hallroom plno before putting it into Lease plno.

Please show *all* relevant info: DDL, input table data, code you ran, output table data and the error message.